# Entity Framework Code First error

Tags: deployment, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

Experts,

We're trying to deploy a project to a SQL Server but see a weird error:

"`The entity type EEntityInfo is not part of the model for the current context.`"

The error is triggered from inserting an entity of the specified type (`EEntityInfo`) into its collection in the DbContext.

Until deployment we've been running the project on a local SQL Express instance without any hickups. For deployment I tried to just clean up the SQLEXPRESS DB, create a new DB on the production SQL Server and then import the SQLEXPRESS DB (including data) to it.

The new DB is an exact copy as far as I can see but now I get these kinds of errors. Is there some metadata I'm unaware of, and that might have been left out of the import process? (The __MigrationHistory table *was* included and contains one record, identical to the original.)

Could it be that the access to the production SQL Server is different?

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: I experimented with different connection strings and, indeed, this was the problem. I don't know if the problem was the presence of meta data but when I recreated them using the server explorer (without meta data) the problem was resolved. 

If you care to convert your comment to a reply I'll go ahead and credit it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be caused when there is meta data present in the connection string. Take the metadata tag out as suggested [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/data/jj556606.aspx#Connection)